# Call valueForKey on an empty NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, nsdictionary

In my code, I called `valueForKey` on an empty `NSDictionary` object, and noticed that the application did crash. But as far as I know, if a message is sent to an empty object, the application will not crash. Can someone help me explain the contradiction here? Thank you very much.

Here is my code:

```
if ([[storedManagedObject valueForKey:@"objectId"] isEqualToString:[record valueForKey:@"objectId"]]) {
    [self updateManagedObject:[storedRecords objectAtIndex:currentIndex] withRecord:record];
} else {
    [self newManagedObjectWithClassName:className forRecord:record];
}
```

where in some scenarios, `storedManagedObject` object is nil.

Answer (score 1):

Your crash is happening because `isEqualToString` type-checks the value before comparing it. If you just use `isEqual` instead, the behavior when passing a nil parameter will be more like what you expect:

```
if ([[storedManagedObject valueForKey:@"objectId"] isEqual:[record valueForKey:@"objectId"]]) {
```

See [Cocoa documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html):

> In all `isEqualToType:` methods of the Cocoa frameworks, `nil` is not a
>   valid parameter and implementations of these methods may raise an
>   exception upon receiving a `nil`. However, for backward compatibility,
>   `isEqual:` methods of the Cocoa frameworks do accept `nil`, returning `NO`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but in my code, when the storedManagedObject is null, the application does not crash. When the storedManagedObject is empty, it just jumps over to execute the code the else condition.

Comment: That's exactly what I would expect. Sending any message to nil will simply return nil and will not crash. Actually, based on the code you provided, the crash occurs when `[record valueForKey:@"objectId"]` returns nil. Calling `isEqualToString:nil` *will* crash.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your explanation. I am much clearer on this now. Previously, I thought a deallocated object and nil were the same thing, but now I know that nil points to a predefined space in memory. PS: I tried that calling isEqualToString:nil will not crash the app. I think only a deallocated object calling isEqualToString: will cause crash.